# Access Control for Menu Pro Zend Framework Techniques?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

Hi I have a web project setup with Zend_Acl / Role based access control.

I have a menu table setup as follows:
id             | INT(11)
name           | VARCHAR(50)
access_level   | VARCHAR(50)

currently, the access level field is set to null for all menus.

In the layout:

```
$this->layout()->adminMenu = $this->action('render', 'menu', null, array('menu' => $this->adminMenuId));
```

The Render action of menu Controller:

```
public function renderAction()
    {
        $menu = $this->_request->getParam('menu');
        $mdlMenuItems = new Model_Menuitem();
        $menuItems = $mdlMenuItems->getItemByMenu($menu);

        if (count($menuItems) > 0)
        {
            foreach ($menuItems as $item)
            {
                $label = $item->label;
                if(!empty($item->link))
                {
                    $uri = $item->link;
                }
                else
                {
                    $uri = '/page/' . $item->page_id;
                }
            $itemArray[] = array(   'label' => $label,
                                    'uri' => $uri);
            }
            $container = new Zend_Navigation($itemArray);
            $this->view->navigation()->setContainer($container);
        }
    }
```

The Acl Details:

```
            $acl->addRole(new Zend_Acl_Role('guest'));
        $acl->addRole(new Zend_Acl_Role('readonly'), 'guest');
        $acl->addRole(new Zend_Acl_Role('administrator'), 'readonly');
```

//setup access rules
        $acl->allow(null, array('index', 'error'));

```
//guest can only read content and login
        $acl->allow('guest', 'page', array('index', 'error'));
        $acl->allow('guest', 'user', array('login'));
        $acl->deny('guest', 'menu', array('render'));
        $acl->allow('administrator', null);
```

What steps should I take to make sure the menu does not render for guests?

Answer (score -1):

You can access the identity of an authorised user with the following

```
    $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
    $identity = $auth->getIdentity();
```